# How do I add arguments to my build in the tasks.json file in vscode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am trying to compile a c++ project in visual studio code. After some research, I think the `tasks.json` file in the `.vscode` folder creates some task that is executed whenever I want to run or compile my code.

My program needs some arguments (i want to use the typical `int argc, char** argv`), and I have some desired values for those arguments with which I'll test my code.

How do I pass those arguments?

I also read that you can use the run tab and pass the commands in a `launch.json`. But that doesn't easily allow me to use the debug function, I'd probably need to learn gdb for that. Which I can do, but I don't know if there is an easier solution to my problem here.

I tried adding another build in the `tasks.json` file, although when I tried running it it didn't seem to work. I hope I had built it correctly.

Comment: arguments for `argv` need to be specified in `launch.json`

Comment: If the research includes the official documentation, you should be up and running within an hour or so.

Comment: See the args: part of launch.json: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_customize-debugging-with-launchjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_customize-debugging-with-launchjson) it should look like this: `"args": [],` inside the [] place your arguments separated by commas.